# Installing ezgraphics in google Collab

Tags: python, graphics

I am trying to install ezgraphics module by pip install ezgraphics in google colab. When using pip intall  ezgraphics, is gives ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ezgraphics (from versions: none) and ERROR: No matching distribution found for ezgraphics

using pip install it gives : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ezgraphics (from versions: none) and ERROR: No matching distribution found for ezgraphics

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the package first and follow the instructions from [www.ezgraphics.org](http://www.ezgraphics.org/Software/Download)